# numpy: fast way of creating a matrix with entries c_i * C_{ij}

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, scipy

I'm looking for a fast way of creating a new matrix `A_{ij}` from a given vector `b_i` and another
matrix `C_{ij}`. The components of the new matrix should have the form

```
A_{ij} = b_i * C_{ij}.
```

So far I am using `dot(diag(b), C)`, but the dot product naturally has a lot of multiplications
with zero, which is quite inefficient. Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm wondering about the intent here. mathematically, the product `b_i*C_{ij}` should be a vector `A_j`, not an i-by-j matrix, right?

Comment: Christoph, no, that would be the case if I summed over i, which is not what I want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `*`, the element-wise product with the appropriate broadcasting:

```
>>> b = array([1,2,3])
>>> C = arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> dot(diag(b), C)
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  8, 10],
       [18, 21, 24]])
>>> atleast_2d(b).T * C
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  8, 10],
       [18, 21, 24]])
```

`atleast_2d(b).T` (or `b.reshape(-1,1)`) reshapes the vector `b` to a column vector.

Comment: so, does the vector argument in the hadamard product get automatically expanded to a diagonal matrix? cause afaik, the hadamard product is only for matrices of identical dimensions, right?

Comment: @Christoph: I removed the confusing term Hadamard product because you're right: `*` isn't always the Hadamard product. No intermediate matrix is built up; [Numpy's broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) applies, just like in the scalar product of a matrix (`C * 2`, for example).

Comment: I also like `b[:,None] * C` but its a matter of taste.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you! It seems to be about twice as fast as my old solution for a 10000x10000 random matrix.

Comment: @henrikr: if you don't need the original `C` after this computation is done, you can perform it in-place with `C *= b.reshape(-1,1)`.

Comment: @larsmans: Thanks! Unfortunately I still need the original C.

Comment: @larsmans thx for the clarification about broadcasting, pretty tricky. can be really useful, but also really destructive if you're not on your toes w.r.t to matrix math. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [einsum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
>>> b = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> C = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> np.einsum('i,ij->ij', b, C)
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  8, 10],
       [18, 21, 24]])
```

On my machine, this method is faster than both

```
np.dot(np.diag(b), C)
```

and

```
np.atleast_2d(b).T * C
```

For 100,000 loops, einsum takes 1.16 seconds, dot takes 1.61 seconds and atleast_2d takes 2.03 seconds.

If you are familiar with [Einstein summation notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation), then einsum is an incredibly useful function. It is easier to formulate many simple linear algebra operations using index notation, and the added speed of execution is just icing on the cake.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the matrix to an array, perform (broadcast) array multiplication, and convert back:

```
np.matrix(b * np.asarray(C))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
b[:,np.newaxis] * C
```

or

```
b[:,None] * C
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answers already given, and trying out a new (but inefficient method), I come with the following timings.

- einsum: 0.54 s (Thycydides)
- broadcasting: 0.44 s (larsmans)
- dot diagonal: 15.6 s (henrikr, TS)
- sparse dia matrix: 16.8 s (own try, failed miserably :-p)

If I repeat einsum and broadcasting each ten times (more timing accuracy), I find:

- einsum: 5.2 s
- broadcasting: 4.5 s

Here is the testing code for it:

```
import timeit
from scipy.sparse.dia import dia_matrix
import numpy as np

def get_bc():
    N = 10000
    M = 10000
    b = np.random.random(size=N)
    c = np.random.random(size=[N, M])
    return b, c

def multiply_dot_diag():
    global b, c
    return np.dot(np.diag(b), c)

def multiply_broadcast():
    global b, c
    return np.atleast_2d(b).T * c

def mulitply_sparse():
    global b, c
    N = b.size
    return dia_matrix((b, 0), shape=[N, N]).todense().dot(c)

def multiply_einsum():
    global b, c
    return np.einsum('i,ij->ij', b, c)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global b, c
    b, c = get_bc()
    print (b, c)

    print (timeit.timeit(multiply_einsum, number=1))
    print (timeit.timeit(multiply_broadcast, number=1))
    print (timeit.timeit(multiply_dot_diag, number=1))
    print (timeit.timeit(mulitply_sparse, number=1))

    np.testing.assert_array_equal(multiply_dot_diag(), multiply_broadcast())
    np.testing.assert_array_equal(multiply_dot_diag(), mulitply_sparse())
    np.testing.assert_array_equal(multiply_dot_diag(), multiply_einsum())
```